# topology of uniform convergence on compacts and strong operator topology

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

I am trying to understand the proof for some lemma in a book, but the part the authors label as trivial is not trivial to me at all. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the *trivial* part of the lemma:

$X$ is a Banach space, $A$ is a function from a compact set $K \subset \mathbb R$ into $L(X)$.
If $A$ is continuous for the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $X$ then $A$ is continuous for the strong operator topology.

Comment: Could you explain what "uniform convergence on compact sets" entails? Because to me it just seems like you need to take the compact set to be a singleton to conclude SOT convergence. Perhaps I am wrong, though.